# Where is the data queued with a BufferedReader?

Tags: java, io

I am reading a large csv from a web service Like this:

`br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(website.openStream(), "UTF-16"));`

I read line by line and write into a database. The writing into a database is the bottleneck of this operation and I am wondering if it is possible that I will "timeout" with the webservice so I get the condition where the webservice just cuts the connection because I am not reading anything from it...

Or does the BufferedReader just buffer the stream into memory until I read from it?

Comment: how slow are you expecting the db to be?  i.e. what kind of delays could there be in reading from the socket?

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible that the webservice stream will timeout while you are writing to the db.  If the db is really slow enough that this might timeout, then you may need to copy the file locally before pushing it into the db.

Comment: Yeah, one option would be to download it to your local machine and then read it from there; the other would be to actually buffer the data for several rows and writing them together as a batch; the third option that comes to mind is to have two threads - one for reading and buffering data for several rows, and one for writing it to the database.

Comment: @carlspring - obviously making the database faster is a solution.  having multiple threads doesn't help unless you are willing to have the entire file in memory (which is a bad design).

Comment: No... reading the entire file in memory is a bad idea. But... bufferring a few lines of the CSV should be within reason.

Comment: @carlspring - that's already happening in the BufferedReader, what's the point of adding a secondary buffering mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

[BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) will, as you have speculated, read the contents of the stream into memory. Any calls to `read` or `readLine` will read data from the buffer, not from the original stream, assuming the data is already available in the buffer. The advantage here is that data is read in larger batches, rather than requested from the stream at each invocation of `read` or `readLine`.

You will likely only experience a timeout like you describe if you are reading large amounts of data. I had some trouble finding a credible reference but I have seen several mentions of the default buffer size on `BufferedReader` being 8192 bytes (8kb). This means that if your stream is reading more than 8kb of data, the buffer could potentially fill and cause your process to wait on the DB bottleneck before reading more data from the stream.

If you think you need to reserve a larger buffer than this, the `BufferedReader` constructor is overloaded with a second parameter allowing you to specify the size of the buffer in bytes. Keep in mind, though, that unless you are moving small enough pieces of data to buffer the entire stream, you could run into the same problem even with a larger buffer.

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(website.openStream(), "UTF-16"), size);
```

will initialize your `BufferedReader` with a buffer of `size` bytes.

EDIT:

After reading @Keith's comment, I think he's got the right of it here. If you experience timeouts the smaller buffer will cause you to read from the socket more frequently, hopefully eliminating that issue. If he posts an answer with that you should accept his.

Comment: It's only a valid fix if he can buffer the entirety of the data from the stream. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I actually wouldn't expect any problem at all, unless your database is  REALLY slow (takes more than 30 seconds to insert lines contained in 8kB of CSV).  But if that is the case, adjust the buffer size DOWN so that you read from the socket more frequently as you are inserting into the DB.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Brian's answer.

Furthermore, I would recommend you have a look at my [csv-db-tools on GitHub](https://github.com/carlspring/csv-db-tools). The `csv-db-importer` module illustrates how to import large CSV files into the database. The code is optimized to insert one row at a time and keep the memory free from data buffered from large CSV files.

Comment: the issue isn't memory management (although that could _also_ be a problem), but of socket timeouts.

Comment: Well, in this case, set socket's timeout to a reasonable value and read from it's stream and then write to the database.

Comment: you can't always control the socket timeouts.  for instance, there may be a firewall in between the client and server with a fixed idle timeout.

Answer (score 0):

BufferedReader just reads in chunks into an internal buffer, whose default size is unspecified but has been 4096 chars for many years. It doesn't do anything while you're not calling it.

But I don't think your perceived problem even exists. I don't see how the web service will even know. Write timeouts in TCP are quite difficult to implement. Some platforms have APIs for that, but they aren't supported by Java.

Most likely the web service is just using a blocking mode socket and it will just block in its write if you aren't reading fast enough.